# Can't get dropdown buttons to sit next to each other on Bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Before I begin, my apologies if this is a stupid question. We've been looking for a mega menu for our site and found this code:
https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/bootstrap-mega-menu

It seemed easy to edit so I began making changes and came out with this:

```
<div class="container">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="navbar-header">
<button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".js-navbar-collapse">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
<!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MegaMenu</a>-->
</div>


<!-- OPEN -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse js-navbar-collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">

<li class="dropdown mega-dropdown float-button"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Holidays <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right"></span></a>

<ul class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu row">

<li class="col-sm-3">
<ul>
<li class="dropdown-header">Destination 1</li> 
<li class="dropdown-listing"><a href="#">Choice 1</a></li>
<li class="dropdown-listing"><a href="#">Choice 2</a></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li class="dropdown-header">Destination 2</li>
<li class="dropdown-listing"><a href="#">Choice 1</a></li>
<li class="dropdown-listing"><a href="#">Choice 2</a></li>
</ul>   
</li>

<li class="col-sm-3">
<ul>
<li class="dropdown-header">Destination 3</li>
<li class="dropdown-listing"><a href="#">Choice 1</a></li>
<li class="dropdown-listing"><a href="#">Choice 2</a></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li class="col-sm-3">
<ul>
<li class="dropdown-header">Destination 4</li>
<li class="dropdown-listing"><a href="#">Choice 1</a></li>
<li class="dropdown-listing"><a href="#">Choice 2</a></li>

</ul>
</li>

<li class="col-sm-3">
<ul>  
<li class="dropdown-header">Destination 5</li>
<li class="dropdown-listing"><a href="#">Choice 1</a></li>
<li class="dropdown-listing"><a href="#">Choice 2</a></li>
<li class="dropdown-listing"><a href="#">Choice 3</a></li>
<li class="dropdown-listing"><a href="#">Choice 4</a></li>
<li class="dropdown-listing"><a href="#">Choice 5</a></li>    
</ul>      
</li>

</ul>
</li>

<!-- CLOSE  --> 

</div>
<!-- /.nav-collapse -->
</nav>
</div>
```

It seems to be working just fine however I wanted to add a second dropdown to the navbar and that is where things started to go wrong. I duplicated this part of the code:

```
<!-- OPEN -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse js-navbar-collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">

<li class="dropdown mega-dropdown float-button"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Holidays <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right"></span></a>

<ul class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu row">

<li class="col-sm-3">
<ul>
<li class="dropdown-header">Destination 1</li> 
<li class="dropdown-listing"><a href="#">Choice 1</a></li>
<li class="dropdown-listing"><a href="#">Choice 2</a></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li class="dropdown-header">Destination 2</li>
<li class="dropdown-listing"><a href="#">Choice 1</a></li>
<li class="dropdown-listing"><a href="#">Choice 2</a></li>
</ul>   
</li>

<li class="col-sm-3">
<ul>
<li class="dropdown-header">Destination 3</li>
<li class="dropdown-listing"><a href="#">Choice 1</a></li>
<li class="dropdown-listing"><a href="#">Choice 2</a></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li class="col-sm-3">
<ul>
<li class="dropdown-header">Destination 4</li>
<li class="dropdown-listing"><a href="#">Choice 1</a></li>
<li class="dropdown-listing"><a href="#">Choice 2</a></li>

</ul>
</li>

<li class="col-sm-3">
<ul>  
<li class="dropdown-header">Destination 5</li>
<li class="dropdown-listing"><a href="#">Choice 1</a></li>
<li class="dropdown-listing"><a href="#">Choice 2</a></li>
<li class="dropdown-listing"><a href="#">Choice 3</a></li>
<li class="dropdown-listing"><a href="#">Choice 4</a></li>
<li class="dropdown-listing"><a href="#">Choice 5</a></li>    
</ul>      
</li>

</ul>
</li>

<!-- CLOSE  -->
```

and pasted it directly underneath. It creates another working menu but it is sat underneath the first one rather than to the right as I had expected. What am I doing wrong? I'd like them to sit side by side when not collapsed.

Fresh eyes and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you looking like this? https://jsfiddle.net/azeste1b/3/

Comment: I have added answer please check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you want this https://bootsnipp.com/user/snippets/Al77D

```
.mega-dropdown {
  position: static !important;
  width: 100%;
}
```

change this to

```
.mega-dropdown {
  position: static !important;
}
```

just remove the `width:100%;` it is causing first menu to take entire width

Comment: @Lisharts my pleasure :), please accept the answer.